# JPEG image with filename patern DSC*.JPG are not rendered

Tags: django

I am using django 2.2 to upload imaged files.  Files are uploaded correctly in MEDIA_ROOT.  Most images are rendered as expected.  Except for the ones with filename like "DSC*.jpg" which were not rendered even though the image tag as seen in inspect correctly pointing to actual files in the media directory.
Anyone experienced this problem before?  I would really appreciatred it if anyone could shed some light into this problem.

There were no error messages.  The images just weren't rendered. 
I am at a lost and ready to implement a clean_filename method for these DSC* files, or change the filename before saving.  But only if it is absolutely necessary.
pax

Comment: How are you serving your media files? When you say they are not rendered, can you see in your browser`s dev tools the request for those files being made successfully?

Comment: A `*` character should not be valid for a filename. Are you sure the file is being uploaded successfully?

Comment: In my template:  <img class="thumbnails" alt="" src="{% static 'media/' %}{{ x.image_file_path }}">

Comment: Iain Shelvington - Yes.  This is in "inspect" tool:  <a href="/static/media/images/DSC_2655.JPG" data-lightbox="upload" data-title="Liparis plantaginea">
                                        <img class="thumbnails" alt="" src="/static/media/images/DSC_2655.JPG">
                                    </a>

Comment: The file is in media root.  ~/webapps/static_media/media/images/ folder

Comment: The "*" is just a wildcard.   I have tested many different file name patterns.  All others shown up in hte browser, except those started with "DSC".  And to confirm again.  These DSC files are uploaded successfully to media/images folder.

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: Ah!  Mystery solved.  the mode of uploaded DSC*.jpg are 600.   They suddenly appeared when I changed their mode to 664.

Comment: I am using Apache 2